# Is it possible to find Voyager in Elite Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

When playing Elite Dangerous, I have noticed that when pulling into a station sometimes there have been advertisements to see the Voyager probes.

I was wondering if this was just to add flavor to the world, or if you could actually go and see them. If so, where would they be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Voyagers were one of the Easter Eggs in the beta and launch of Elite Dangerous.

The Solar System was claimed to be modelled as close as possible during development. [Someone checked for the Voyagers and found them](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/2owop5/this_is_the_secret_that_was_in_the_changelog/).

This was mentioned by the developers at launch, and made it into several articles, e.g. [this one](https://www.seeker.com/voyager-probes-found-in-online-elite-dangerous-universe-1769425518.html).

A quick search yielded various youtube instruction videos and reddit threads. [A sample quote](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/31luf0/finding_the_voyagers/):

> Once you get to the Sol system, fly around for a bit and look for a signal source approximately 2 million LS away. The most important thing to know is that the signal source does not show up in the navigation pane. It's one that you will see out your window, and it will be labeled "Deep Space." You will know it's one of the Voyagers because it will be approximately 2 million LS away. (Voyager 1 was about 2.3 million LS from Saturn when I found it). I hope this helps anyone who was looking for the probes. It is so awesome that Frontier put them in. And, bonus, you can hear part of the Golden Record recording!

Answer (score 3):

The Various deep space probes (both Voyagers, one of the Pionner probes and I think new Horizons all exist in the Sol System), and are all now (at least since Early 2019) discoverable via the Full System Scan - they are quite far out, and once 'honked' they will appear on the Navigation pane - you no longer have to try to search for a signal.